# How to pass value of an input range to a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you get the value of an input range slider into a variable?  Below is the range I'm using. Suppose I drag the range to 12, then I need "12" as the variable that I want to then pass to a function.

```
 <input type="range" min="1" max="30" value="15" />
```

Edit: I don't want a button to confirm the value or something, I want that everytime the value is changed, it gets passed to the function, so it'll be dynamic!

PS: It may not be the best question out there, but I've honestly tried looking for an answer before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give an id to your field:

```
 <input id="myRange" type="range" min="1" max="30" value="15" />
```

then:

```
 $('#myRange').val();
```

First step it is not really required, but it makes things easier.

You can do this in every form field element:

```
 $('selector').val();
```

And you will get its value.

UPDATE FOR YOUR QUESTION:

Use .change event to bind a function that make whatever you want to do with this value, for example:

```
$('#myRange').change(function(){
    var myVar = $(this).val();
    alert(myVar);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to bind to the `change` event:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="30" value="15" />

$("input").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use register an event on the input:

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="30" value="15" oninput="alert(this.value)" />
```

you could of course also call a function in the `oninput` field.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtap/e1j9fgj0/)

`<input id="field" type="range" min="1" max="30" value="15" />`

```
var input = document.getElementById('field');
console.info(input.defaultValue); // value default (15)
input.onchange = function () {
  console.info(input.value); // value change
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by adding a listener to the field's `input` event, updating your variable every time it fires.

```js
var input=document.querySelector("input"),
    value=input.value;
console.log(value);
input.addEventListener("input",function(){
    value=this.value;
    console.log(value);
},0);
```

```html
<input max="30" min="1" type="range" value="15">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the input an Id. Then use
For JQuery

```
Var a = $('#whateverId').val();
```

For JavaScript

```
Var a = getElementById('whateverID).innerHtml;
```

Comment: this is "dynamic". variable will not be changed